Audio Reconstruction from a normalized spectrogram vector
Sorry if its a beginner question, but I want to ask if there is a way to reconstruct an audio from a normalized spectrogram vector?. I have trained model normalizing the spectrograms and I would like to reconstruct the audio with high reconstruced quality. I tried using griffin-lim algorithm but the audio reconstructed is far from the original clip. Any directions that you can point me to?
I tried reconstructing using griffin_lim algorithm, I am using tensorflow (Some suggested to its easier to use librosa but its not optimized for using with tensorflow hence i had to use tensorflow; that is what I think). For spectrogram extraction, i use the default tf.signal.stft() and Z-normalized it for training. Now, I want to convert the spectrogram back into audio and this is what i have used:
def griffin_lim(spectrogram, frame_length =256, frame_step=128, fft_length=256, iterations=100):
spectrogram = tf.cast(spectrogram, tf.complex64)

def invert_spectrogram(spectrogram):
    return tf.signal.inverse_stft(
        spectrogram,
        frame_length=frame_length,
        frame_step=frame_step,
        fft_length=fft_length,
        window_fn=tf.signal.inverse_stft_window_fn(frame_step)
    )

for i in range(iterations):
    reconstructed_waveform = invert_spectrogram(spectrogram)
    spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(reconstructed_waveform, frame_length, frame_step, fft_length)
    spectrogram = tf.complex(tf.math.real(spectrogram), tf.math.imag(spectrogram))
return reconstructed_waveform
```



is there is a way to reconstruct an audio from a normalized spectrogram vector (with high quality)

Not really. Once the phase is gone you have lost half of the information. While griffin lim is one way to reconstruct sone of the phase spectrum no algorithm that I know of comes anywhere near "high quality" for something like, for example, music.

Hi, thank you for your response. I am working with short audio clips where I am changing the original audio after spectrogram conversion. I was wondering on how I could reconstruct the changed clip as close as possible. I used griffin lim however, reconstructed quality is far from original. Any directions that I could march?

@BlindTunes: can you preserve at least me phase information through out your signal chain?
